# Xtext and Xtend: Interfaces inside folder

Tags: jvm, xtext, xtend

I saw that the classes are generated inside separate folder/package. But the interface files are generated in the root folder instead of generating inside the specific package.

Here is the code for JVM Inferrer:

```
   def dispatch void infer(Repository repo, 
                IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor acceptor, 
                boolean isPrelinkingPhase) {   
      acceptor.accept(repo.toInterface(repo.name, [])) [      
          documentation = repo.documentation
          annotations += annotationRef(REPOSITORY);
          superTypes += JPAREPOSITORY.typeRef(repo.type.cloneWithProxies,Long.typeRef); 
    ]
  }
```

Here is the model:

```
import dsltest.models.Plant
import dsltest.models.Customer

package dsltest.repositories {

 repo PlantRepository : Plant {}
 repo CustomerRepository : Customer {}
}
```

Here is the generated files:

[screen shot of src-gen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doF3f.png)

How to make interface to generate inside dsltest-> respositories -> CustomerRepository.java

Answer (score 0):

the first parameter of the toInterface method should be a qualifiedName e.g.

```
accept(entity.toInterface(entity.fullyQualifiedName,[]))[
...
]
```

or

```
accept(entity.toInterface(EcoreUtil2.getContainerOfType(entity,  Package).name+"."+entity.name,[]))[
...
]
```

Comment: toInterface (String, initializer). So Type mismatch: cannot convert from QualifiedName to String. The second one is : Bounds mismatch: The type argument <Package> is not a valid substitute for the bounded type parameter <T extends EObject> of the method getContainerOfType(EObject, Class<T>)

Comment: I had already tried this before. Couldn't solve this. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Can you share a complete grammar and inferrer that I can copy and paste

Comment: It is very lengthy. Its difficult to share here. The problem in this is, i couldn't able to add fullyQualifiedName as toInterface() parameter type. It accepts only strings.

Comment: Is there any way to generate the classes in different packages by changing the package names in JvmInferrer?

Comment: i dont get that point, what is what i suggested ```accept(entity.toInterface("a"+".b"+".I"+entity.name,[]))[```